# Auto run console application not need click on .exe file

Tags: c#, console

I have a console application built with C# that is sending email application.

When someone places an order it will send an email to customers.

This is code from my application:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int sleepingTime = int.Parse(ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["SleepInMiliSecond"]);
    while (true)
    {
        StartRunning();
        Log("Sleep for a while...");
        Thread.Sleep(sleepingTime);
    }            
    //Environment.Exit(0);
}
private static void StartRunning()
{
    Log("Process Start Running...");
    ProcessWarranty();
    CheckEmailSendingResult();
    Log("Process End...");

}
```

My problem is the app only working when I click on .exe file. Is there any way of making it automatically send email without clicking on the .exe file?

Comment: Which Application do you use for order placement? Is it possible to run the exe file from that application?

Comment: Should i convert it to window service?

Comment: It is usual to use operations like Email and fax sending as services. It will more stable and you will not to worry about it running automatically.

Answer (score 0):

In this case I would have made the console application into a service or background process. Or you will have to have some kind of trigger event that runs the exe file.

The most easy (and dirty) way is to have an eternally running while loop that checks if a mail should be sent, sends it if necessary, and terminates only if you press ctrl+c or something similiar.

```
while(true)
{
    if(aNewEmailShouldBeSent)
    {    
        SendEmail("somemail.txt");
        Console.WriteLine("I sent an email");
    }

    //Wait some time in order to "slow down" the loop
    Thread.Sleep(10000);
}
```

If you want to do it a more proper way I would recommend the WindowsService library from Peter Kottas: https://github.com/PeterKottas/DotNetCore.WindowsService

Answer (score 0):

you can use timer in your application and base on timer interval send email, like this:

```
 private static System.Timers.Timer EmailTimer;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int sleepingTime = int.Parse(ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["SleepInMiliSecond"]);
        EmailTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
        EmailTimer.Elapsed += Timer_Elapsed;
        EmailTimer.Enabled = true;
        EmailTimer.Start();
    }
    private static void Timer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        EmailTimer.Enabled = false;
        try
        {
            StartRunning();

        }
        finally
        {
            EmailTimer.Enabled = true;
        }

    }

    private static void StartRunning()
    {
        Log("Process Start Running...");
        ProcessWarranty();
        CheckEmailSendingResult();
        Log("Process End...");

    }
```

Comment: Are you sure this work?Could i convert it to Window Service?